# How to navigate to a tableview embed inside a navigation Controller from a different viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a tablview embed in a navigation controller.
I created a new viewController outside of the navigation controller.

In the new viewController I created the following code to navigate to the tableview but got "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier datacell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard" error.

Where did I go wrong?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let startButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
            button.setTitle(" START ", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = .blue
            button.setTitleColor(.yellow, for: .highlighted)
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToHeritageSelection), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }()
        
        view.addSubview(startButton)
        startButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        startButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        startButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        
    }


    @objc private func goToHeritageSelection() {
        let vc = AncientHeritageTableViewController()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are dequeuing cells, but you have not registered that custom cell to the table in the first place. What you need to do is to use `register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)`. If you created your cell programmatically, use `tableViewName.register(CustomCellName.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")`. If otherwise and you used Nib instead, then use `tableViewName.register(UINib(nibName: "NameOfNibFile", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")`.

Comment: But the problem error did not appear when I make the tableViewController the "initial View Controller".  It happen when I created a new viewController and set the new viewController as the "Initial View".

Comment: Well, then probably the `register` method does not get called when you initiate an instance of `AncientHeritageTableViewController`. Make sure that `register` method is getting called.